# how to create animated pie chart in android?

Tags: java, android, animation, pie-chart

How can i draw an animated pie-chart? I have drawn a chart and below is the code. I now need the chart to become animated when it gets loaded on to the screen. How can I achieve this and can anyone give me an idea of what I should look for or where?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure about what you want to do. What animation do you want ? Do you want a PieChart that could replace an indeterminate ProgressBar ?

Comment: where is the code? do you have a view diplaying the pie chart? do you want an in animation or something more complicated like animating one of the chart values? pleas explain better

Answer (score 3):

I made small example. maybe it  be helpful for you.
[Animated pie char.](https://github.com/binaryroot/pie-chart-animation/tree/master/animation_ic_lauch)
The implementation was based on the SurfaceView.
In SurfaceView I set thread. This thread calculate animation with 60 FPS.

```
 long ticksPS = 1000 / 60;
 long startTime;
 long sleepTime;
     while (running) {
       sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
         try {
            if (sleepTime > 0)
               Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
         else
               Thread.sleep(10);
         } catch (Exception e) {}
 }
```

Rendering by using the method canvas.drawArc. Each frame increases sweepAngle.

```
          if((sweepAngle+startAngle) <= endAngle){
             sweepAngle+=2;
          }
```

For more details you can see on github.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the: [ChartDroid](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/) library for Android.